# Monero Fork (Genesis Block)

Tags: blockchain, genesisblock

I'm performing a Monero (XMR) fork, but I'm not sure how to generate a genesis block. Could you help me? Investigate a little and talk about a print parameter in the deamon, but that parameter no longer exists. I am using version 0.11 of monero. Many thanks to all beforehand. Great greeting!!
PS: I have been told that this topic may be duplicated with another. I need a step-by-step tutorial on how to create a new geneisis block or how to create a private blockchain, which I believe should be the same steps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a new Monero genesis block?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/how-can-i-create-a-new-monero-genesis-block)

Comment: hi scoobybejesus....thank you for your answer, but that link not explain the steps to generate new genesis block. However, I saw that a few days ago and i couldn generate it. Do you know a tutorial about this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you change the GENESIS_TX of "cryptonote_config.h", input following commands in your terminal:

Creat node1:

> ./monerod --testnet --no-igd --hide-my-port --testnet-data-dir
>   ~/test/node1 --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --add-exclusive-node
>   127.0.0.1:38080 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:48080

Creat node2:

> ./monerod --testnet --testnet-p2p-bind-port 38080
>   --testnet-rpc-bind-port 38081 --no-igd --hide-my-port --testnet-data-dir ~/test/node2 --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:28080 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:48080

Creat node3:

> ./monerod --testnet --testnet-p2p-bind-port 48080
>   --testnet-rpc-bind-port 48081 --no-igd --hide-my-port --testnet-data-dir ~/test/node3 --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:28080 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:38080

Creat wallet1:

> ./monero-wallet-cli --testnet --trusted-daemon --generate-new-wallet
>   ~/test/test1

Creat wallet2:

> ./monero-wallet-cli --testnet --daemon-port 38081 --trusted-daemon
>   --generate-new-wallet ~/test/test2

Creat wallet3:

> ./monero-wallet-cli --testnet --daemon-port 48081 --trusted-daemon
>   --generate-new-wallet ~/test/test3

[More tips.](https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet)

Comment: You say "After you change the GENESIS_TX of cryptonote_config.h" - but what do you change GENESIS_TX to???

Comment: Are all these nodes on the same server? Do you have to have 3 nodes?