# Creating a genesis block, but it doesnt work, for an entire day

Tags: monerod, genesisblock

Now its late at night, i am drunk and angry. I cant create a new genesis block.

I know that this has been asked at least twice before, but the answeres are more cryptic than predictions from my local palmreader.

"Go here and screw around with the genesis tx and nonce"
The devil is in the details.
Yes, i did, i put the genesis hash in the config to an empty string and the nonce to 0, for both test and live. It pretty much gives me the error that it cannot find that hard-fork in the db, no shit. Obviously not the right thing to do. This only works if i let the genesis hash be the same as the live hash, and then i cant really change any setting or screw around with it.

"I've helpfully decoded the genesis tx so you know/can guess what to change:
version
01
unlock time (varint, height, 60 here)
3c..."
[How can I create a new Monero genesis block?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/how-can-i-create-a-new-monero-genesis-block?newreg=d0b1044c62df469589e771ac38652c7d)
is this a binary file that must be edited, based on the hex-postions(?) so we are talking data.mdb?

But i really like "After you change the GENESIS_TX of "cryptonote_config.h bla bla testnetwork" [Monero Fork (Genesis Block)](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/6294/monero-fork-genesis-block)
It's nice to know that if i just put in the right setting for generating a genesis node, it will work. If only i could find that out somewhere, like a question forum.

I just realized this might be that it should be all zeros, like the trustedpulickey thing. fuck. well, i might as well post in case of. and drink some more. and go to bed.

well, i get "ERROR   cn      src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_format_utils.cpp:102 Failed to parse transaction from blob"
and if i take some code from Sumokoin for generating the genesis node i also get "ERROR   default src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp:489 failed to parse coinbase tx from hard coded blob", which is funny, does this mean it creates the db with hardcoded settings and stuff in the genesis node and then compares with my settings?

Anyway, since sumokoin gives the same error, i guess this is an old thing, like pre-monero, so i assume you guys have run into it also

Comment: Try drinking more and repeatedly hitting the return key with ferocious rage

Comment: That must be it. Like a noob I only applied face to screen rigously.
I guess that is why I am not payed the big bucks :)