# genesis block with v12 block version

Tags: transaction-data, monero-forks

I'm trying to start a new genesis with v12 block version.

v1 as is explained in depth here

[How can I create a new Monero genesis block?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2886/how-can-i-create-a-new-monero-genesis-block?rq=1)

works without problems.

What info / bytes are needed for v12 different to v1.

Comment: this fork will be different because miners will be more than monero miners. what else is need for v12 block. rct version zero(coinbase transaction)?

Comment: I believe long term block weights are not currently compatible with new chains, so you'd have to implement some new rules for early blocks. There are a number of other changes required that I don't know about... basically it is trial and error and debugging since all others who went before you neglected to make a guide.

Comment: someone can be more specific? debugging monero is a process that need months. we are talking about some more bytes that v12 block need to be acceptable as genesis block.

Comment: what I'm saying is it is probably more complicated than just adding some bytes... the current v12 code is designed around a genesis block that is 2mill blocks old; no matter how you change the genesis block itself, the code will still error out trying to read it unless you patch the code

Answer (score 1):

"v12" refers to the hard fork version, not the tx version. Given that, and by the mere definition a genesis block is the first block mined, what you're asking makes little sense - compounded by the fact you talk of block versions but are actually referencing the miner tx of a genesis block.

If you are trying to fork Monero with a new chain that starts with v12 functionality, it's not the genesis tx that needs changing, rather a bunch of other code.

Comment: jtgrassie fork with block version 1 is working. changes are made on hardfork.cpp so the issue is that block version 12 need more info bytes(more details) than block version 1

Comment: There's no "block" changes required other than major/minor version numbers. But again, you would need to change lots of other code (not just hardfork.cpp) to have a genesis mimic v12. Also, before I answer more, what is your intention for a fork?

Comment: my intention is to c how monero will behave on hand of not tech users. what monero lack is a really big user base. genesis block is changed to have tx version 2(block 12 work only with tx2) nothing else is required as i now... except hardfork.cpp

Comment: I don't see how forking Monero helps "behave on hand of not tech users. what monero lack is a really big user base". Sounds like you are just trying to create a competing fork now.